# Not able to get exact class name

Tags: java, proxy-classes

I am not able to get exact className

**My code is :**

```
venue.getClass.getName();
```

**It's giving output like:**

```
com.venue.Venue_java_assist17_
```

I've to get output like exact `classname: com.venue.Venue`

Comment: Seems like your instance is a proxy.

Comment: Are you using Spring? Hiberate? Something is decorating your classes with [Javassist](http://www.csg.ci.i.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/).

Comment: yes exactly..It's Proxy issue..How can i solve this?

Comment: He is using javaassist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't directly get the class name, since it is a proxy. The only way to get the real class name is to strip of the suffix, e.g.:

```
String cn = "com.venue.Venue_java_assist17_";
System.out.println(cn.substring(0, cn.indexOf('_', cn.lastIndexOf('.'))));
```

If you are using Hibernate, you could use:

```
HibernateProxyHelper.getClassWithoutInitializingProxy(venue);
```